# pivot data using SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, pivot

I'm new to SQL and I'm wondering how to pivot a table like:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1     a    w
2     a    x 
1     b    y
2     b    z
```

Into

```
Col1 a b
1    w y
2    x z
```

I was playing with `GROUP BY` but I can't seem to be able to turn unique rows into columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select col1,
  max(case when col2 = 'a' then col3 end) a,
  max(case when col2 = 'b' then col3 end) b
from yourtable
group by col1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69357/1)

If you are using an RDBMS with a `PIVOT` function (SQL Server 2005+ / Oracle 11g+), then your query would be similar to this (*Note: Oracle syntax below*):

```
select *
from
(
  select col1, col2, col3
  from yourtable
)
pivot
(
  max(col3)
  for col2 in ('a', 'b')
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69357/4)

The last way that you can do this is by using multiple joins on the same table:

```
select t1.col1, 
  t1.col3 a, 
  t2.col3 b
from yourtable t1
left join yourtable t2
  on t1.col1 = t2.col1
  and t2.col2 = 'b'
where t1.col2 = 'a'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69357/9)

All give the result:

```
| COL1 | 'A' | 'B' |
--------------------
|    1 |   w |   y |
|    2 |   x |   z |
```

Comment: so if I have 3 columns then I would just use max(case when col2='c' then col4 end) c ?

Comment: @CAPSLOCK yes, if you had more values that you wanted as columns, then you would just add an additional `max(case..)` statement.

Comment: great answer thanks! can you explain why the max() has to be there

Comment: @CAPSLOCK An aggregate is needed so you will grab the correct result for each column.  If you don't aggregate it you will get data that looks like this -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69357/10.  If you don't or can't aggregate the data, then you would have to perform multiple joins similar to my last edit.

Comment: so instead of max I could do sum for instance?

Comment: @CAPSLOCK yes as long as it is not a string. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you require that the distinct values in Col2 can change without forcing changes on your query definition, you may be looking for an [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube) structure like [SQL Analysis Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Analysis_Services).

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like

```
select * from
(select Col1, Col2, Col3 from TableName) 
pivot xml (max(Col3)
for Col2 in (any) )
```

I'm on a mobile so I can't test if it's working right now.